# Exponential equation: $(3-2\sqrt2)^x + (3+2\sqrt2)^x = 6$

Tags: exponential-function

Equation:
$(3-2\sqrt2)^x + (3+2\sqrt2)^x = 6$

I tried using logarithms and typical operations. Please advice.

Comment: $x = 1$ is an obvious solution (is it the only?)

Comment: You can potentially find all solutions for $x\in\mathbb N$ by assuming $x$ is a natural number and binomially expanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$3-2\sqrt{2} = \dfrac{1}{3+2\sqrt{2}}$$

Now let $(3+2\sqrt{2})^x = t$. We have

$$t+\dfrac{1}{t} = 6$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Call $p=(3-2\sqrt2)^x$ and $q=(3+2\sqrt2)^x$. Note that:

$p+q=6$ and $p\cdot q=1$. So you will get:

$$q^2-6q+1=0$$

and solving that you get:

$$q \in \{3+2\sqrt{2},3-2\sqrt{2}\}$$

Comment: Or $q=3-2\sqrt{2}$ of course... So $x=-1$ is also a solution.

Comment: @Wim, of course!